# How to use SharedPreferences to save String passed as a parameter to another Activity by Intent?

Tags: android, string, android-intent, save, sharedpreferences

I have a simple app that in my first Activity (A) insert a string in Edtittext and clicking on the save button, this string is passed to the next Activity (B) by Intent. So far so good, but the problem here is to implement the SharedPreferences. 
Use the Intent to be the best way to do this, and instantly, by sinal.Apenas need help to save this String Now!

My Activity Segunda:

> private Intent grava;

```
    btSalvarSeg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SalvarSeg);
    btSalvarSeg.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            grava = new Intent(Segunda.this, Main.class);

            grava.putExtra("Matéria 1", etHrSeg1.getText().toString());
            grava.putExtra("Matéria 2", etHrSeg2.getText().toString());
            grava.putExtra("Matéria 3", etHrSeg3.getText().toString());
            grava.putExtra("Matéria 4", etHrSeg4.getText().toString());
            grava.putExtra("Matéria 5", etHrSeg5.getText().toString());
            grava.putExtra("Matéria 6", etHrSeg6.getText().toString());
            grava.putExtra("Matéria 7", etHrSeg7.getText().toString());

            startActivity(grava);
        }

    });
```

The next Activity Main:

> Intent busca;
>    String Mat 1;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    busca = getIntent();

    Mat1 = busca.getStringExtra("Matéria 1");

    tvMainS1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MainS1);
    tvMainS1.setText(Mat1);// Restaura preferências salvas}}
```

What I need to do? Please help me, I await answers :)

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences can be accessed from anywhere as long as you handle it properly, for example by using the default ones you can do it as follows(from any place of your app as long as you have a reference to the context):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editPrefs = prefs.edit();
editPrefs.putBoolean(key, value);
editPrefs.commit();
```

Hope it Helps!

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use SharedPrefrences then you don't need to Pass Values through Intent.

You can easily Set and get Value from Shared Prefrences.

[Here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/) You can see the example.

Comment: I wore this context, but what happens is that when the activity was changed to textview was not yet updated, you had to enter another activity and come back to see what was the intent salvo.Com, by clicking the button it redirects just right with the textview defined already, but you can not save :/

Comment: I just don't get you..Try to describe your effort & problem.